# R Returning all characters after the first underscore

Tags: r, gsub

Sample DATA

```
x=c("AG.av08_binloop_v6","TL.av1_binloopv2")
```

Sample ATTEMPT

```
y=gsub(".*_","",x)
```

Sample DESIRED

```
WANT=c("binloop_v6","binloopv2")
```

Basically I aim to extract all the characters AFTER the first underscore value.

Comment: what if there are two or more consecutive underscore?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the `pattern`, we can change the zero or more any characters (`.*` - here `.` is metacharacter that can match any character) to zero or more characters that is not a `_` (`[^_]*`) from the start (`^`) of the string.

```
sub("^[^_]*_", "", x)
#[1] "binloop_v6" "binloopv2"
```

---

If we don't specify it as such, the `_` will match till the last `_` in the string and uptill that substring will be lost returning 'v6' and 'binloopv2'

---

An easier option would be `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(x, 2, sep = "_")
#[1] "binloop"   "binloopv2"
```

Answer (score 4):

`regexpr` gives the position of first match (in this case `_`). Then `substring` can be used to extract the part of `x` from relevant position to the end (`nchar(x)`)

```
substring(x, regexpr("_", x) + 1, nchar(x))
#[1] "binloop_v6" "binloopv2"
```

Comment: I am guessing that the `substring` option to be the fastest