# R to use stringr::str_extract g

Tags: r

I have a string in a vector like:

```
l <- c("0_Mango_10a"  "0_Orange_10b"  "0_Apple_11)
```

I need to extract Mango_10a, Orange_10b and Apple_11

My current code is :

```
stringr::str_extract(l, "(?<=_)[:alnum:]+")
```

And i get Mango, Orange and Apple.

Could any one help me getting the desired results.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [R Returning all characters after the first underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55424539/r-returning-all-characters-after-the-first-underscore)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `trimws` from `base R` by specifying the `whitespace` as one or more digits(`\\d+`) followed by underscore (`_`)

```
trimws(l, whitespace = "\\d+_")
[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"
```

---

With `stringr`, `str_remove` can be used

```
stringr::str_remove(l, "^\\d+_")
[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"
```

In `str_extract`, the pattern specified is only to match alphanumeric and not `_`.  If we include, it will work

```
stringr::str_extract(l, "(?<=_)[[:alnum:]_]+")
[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two base R options

```
> gsub("^\\d+_", "", l)
[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"

> unlist(regmatches(l, gregexpr("(?<=_).*", l, perl = TRUE)))
[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the text before the first underscore.

Using `sub` in base R -

```
l <- c("0_Mango_10a" , "0_Orange_10b",  "0_Apple_11")

sub('.*?_', '', l)
#[1] "Mango_10a"  "Orange_10b" "Apple_11"
```

Or `stringr::str_remove`.

```
stringr::str_remove(l, '.*?_')
```